# How to add user properties to Service Bus topic output from Javascript Azure Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm working on a TypeScript Azure Function that has an Azure Service bus topic as its output. I can send messages with it without any problem, but I cannot set any metadata as custom property on the message.

I've tried using an object with the same interface as the [ServiceBusMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusmessage?view=azure-node-latest) from the Service Bus Javascript SDK, like this:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {
  const message = {
    body: "my message content",
    applicationProperties: { key: "value" },
  };

  context.bindings.myTopic = message;
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

But the `message` is sent as-is, and the `applicationProperties` is not taken into account. I cannot see them on the Azure Portal in the Service Bus Explorer. The content of the message will be the JSON version of the `message` object.

I've tried with the extension bundles 3 and 4, without success.

I'm using this `function.json` file:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["get", "post"]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "name": "myTopic",
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "queueName": "myTopic",
      "connection": "SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/servicebus-writer/index.js"
}
```

And this `host.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

How can I set those custom properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, there is no way to set metadata using bindings in non-C# languages. The workaround would be to use the Service Bus SDK directly to send out messages.

There is [this feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/df849c4f-f224-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0) that you could up vote to gain more traction.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing